# MySQL - Reserving ID's before the initial auto_increment value

Tags: mysql, sql, innodb, auto-increment

My users table:

```
CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `username` varchar(64) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
ALTER TABLE users AUTO_INCREMENT = 1000;
```

Now I'll start adding records (first user ID will be 1000). Is there any problems in manually adding users before the initial AUTO_INCREMENT value?

```
INSERT INTO `users` (`id`, `username`) VALUES (1, 'something');
# ...
INSERT INTO `users` (`id`, `username`) VALUES (900, 'something');
```

While a normal insert would just use the next increment value

```
INSERT INTO `users` (`username`) VALUES ('something else'); # id: 1000
INSERT INTO `users` (`username`) VALUES ('something else'); # id: 1001
```

Basically I want to reserve the ID's from 1 to 999 so I can add them manually without breaking the `AUTO_INCREMENT`.

Will this create any problems? I have foreign keys referencing this user id too.

Comment: If id has any meaning beyond the internal scope of the database, don't use AUTO_INCREMENT. It will get you in to trouble further down the road.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do what you proposed. Insert values manually and then allow to `AUTO_INCREMENT` to work.

**[`AUTO_INCREMENT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-auto-increment.html):**

> No value was specified for the AUTO_INCREMENT column, so MySQL
>   assigned sequence numbers automatically. You can also explicitly
>   assign 0 to the column to generate sequence numbers. If the column is
>   declared NOT NULL, it is also possible to assign NULL to the column to
>   generate sequence numbers. **When you insert any other value into a
>   AUTO_INCREMENT column, the column is set to that value and the
>   sequence is reset so that the next automatically generated value
>   follows sequentially from the inserted value.**

After reserving range `1-999` the counter starts from `1000`. You need to ensure you won't try to insert duplicate values because you can violate `PRIMARY KEY`.

<kbd>**[`SqlFiddleDemo`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4db79/1/0)**</kbd>

Output:

```
╔═══════╦═══════════╗
║  id   ║ username  ║
╠═══════╬═══════════╣
║    1  ║ something ║
║  999  ║ something ║
║ 1000  ║ new value ║
╚═══════╩═══════════╝
```

Comment: @RickJames Please let me know when the case will be solved.

Answer (score 2):

No as far as I'm aware it won't do, The AUTO_INCREMENT is onlyused when you omit the primary key. More information can be founf here:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/replication-options-master.html